# Using generics in declaring ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, collections

What is the difference between the following ways of declaring `ArrayList`:

1. `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();`
2. `ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Both declarations compile, altough the first one shows warning for unchecked type.

So, why do programmers are using

`ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

instead of the shorter version

`ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: as a safety measure.

Comment: from java7, common is `List<String> data = new ArrayList<>()`